# OrientDB Select name of an an object followed by more than 2 users

Tags: java, sql, count, vertex, orientdb

I have this two classes :

```
public interface Persona {
    @Property("name")
    public void setName(String name);

    @Property("name")
    public String getName();

    @Property("surname")
    public void setSurname(String surname);

    @Property("surname")
    public int getSurname();

    @Property("age")
    public void setAge(int age);

    @Property("age")
    public int getAge();
}
```

and

```
public interface Vettura {
@Property("name")
public void setName(String name);

@Property("name")
public String getName();

@Property("model")
public void setModel(String model);

@Property("model")
public int getModel();

@Adjacency(label = "follower", direction = Direction.IN)
public Iterable<Persona> getFollowers();

@Adjacency(label = "follower",direction = Direction.IN)
public void addFollower(Persona person);
}
```

i am trying (without success) to write a query that display the object "Vettura" only if the followers are more than 2.

how can i write it?

i wrote this one but it give to me all the objects without the filter i desire :

```
for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) graph.command(
            new OCommandSQL("   select  name from Vettura where Vettura.in('follower').count > 1 IN Vettura.in('follower') ")).execute()) {
    System.out.println("- Vettura: " + v.getVertices(Direction.BOTH, "name"));
}
```

thanks in advance and thanks for your attention.

Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select from Vettura where inE('follower').size() > 1;
```

Comment: BTW If working with OrientDB, you do not need the tinkerpop frames annotations! It just makes the code ugly :)